# i want to show two row from sqlite database to list view

Tags: android, sqlite

I have some problem when I want to show two rows in my list view.

When I show one row in my list view it's working well. This is my list view code where I am showing one row

```
 DBHelper db=new DBHelper(this);
    ArrayList<String> names=new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0; i < db.getAllContact().size(); i++){
            names.add(db.getAllContact().get(i).getName());
        }

    ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);
    listview_allContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what problem you are facing and show more of your code?

Comment: in my data base i have three row,but i can only show one row in my list view using this code for (int i=0; i < db.getAllContact().size(); i++)

            names.add(db.getAllContact().get(i).getName()); but i want to show 2 row in my list view,now tell me how can i do this.

Comment: Can you check for whether you are getting all the three rows data from the database by printing log of db.getAllContact(); ?

Comment: i got it from My DBHelper class..i just want to show two row in my list view,using this code i can show only first position data.but i want to show first and second position data,how can i do this.

Comment: post your db.getAllContact(); code, there may be issue with this method.

Answer (score 0):

For showing only first two rows:

```
ArrayList<String> names=new ArrayList<>();
for(int index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
    names.add(db.getAllContact().get(index).getName()); 
}

ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
listview_allContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This code should work fine. I think the problem has to be in your xml. Have you given fixed height(e.g 50dp) to your listview?

Comment: dude,,its show same result,,don't show two row,,it's show only one row in list view.

Comment: @YazdaniChowdhury You need to post more of your code including your xmls and DatabaseHandler class for further help.